# Translate 3....0 into 0......1, Unity3d (Time.time)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to fill image with respect to time the game started, I am getting correct values of time, but I am unable to make algo to convert these values(3...0) to (0....1) To fill Image, like if 3 seconds pass, then image will fill w.r.t 3 seconds.Here is my code so far.

```
private float total_time = 3.0f;
private float end_time;
private float time_change_at;
private float init_time;

void Start()
{
    init_time = Time.time;
    end_time = init_time + total_time;
    time_change_at = total_time - 1.0f;
}
    void Update () 
{
    if (total_time <= 0.0f) 
    {
        return;
    }
    total_time = end_time - Time.time;

    if (total_time >= time_change_at) 
    {
        time_change_at = time_change_at + 1.0f;
    }
    fill_the_bar(total_time);
    string time_to_show = Mathf.Floor((total_time/60.0f)).ToString("00")+":"+(total_time%60).ToString("00");
    print (time_to_show);


}

public void fill_the_bar(float val)
{
 here i want to fill image gradually
 //image.fillAmount
}
```

Comment: "then image will fill w.r.t 3 seconds"....What image? Please explain this

Comment: Are you trying to convert 0...3 to 0...1? If so, I think you could divide the `total_time` by 3.0f.

Comment: initially, total_time returns 3 then it decrease, towards 0 (through Time.time), so here, I want to fill image, 0 to 100%, 
like at intial value 3 image will fill 0.0 percent(not calculated, just rough estimated)
and at 2.5 image will fill 0.4
and at 2 image will fill 0.5
and at 1.5 = 0.8
and at 1 =1 (image completely fills)

Comment: no , i want to convert 3...0 to 0...1 .... (edited) @Sarcoma

Comment: Ah I see, then can you do `Math.abs(total_time - 3.0f) / 3.0f`. I think.

Comment: Yes, exactly, what I need, thanks a lot, it worked fine, You should put these lines into answer tab, I will accept it... :-)

Comment: Great! will do thanks. Though I'm not the sharpest with C#. Let me know if I made an error in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the count using `Math.abs(total_time - 3.0f) / 3.0f` where 3.0f is the `max_time` of the counter.

```
public void fill_the_bar(float total_time)
{
    float max_time = 3.0f

    image.fillAmount = Math.Abs(total_time - 3.0f) / 3.0f
}
```

Comment: its Math.Abs  not Math.abs otherwise, everything is perfect